# Kotlin inline usage

Tags: kotlin, memory-management, inline

I had read a lot of articles and Q&As in the past about the Kotlin `inline` keyword, and before using it I always stopped for a moment to think if it's applicable in the code that I am writing or not.

As far as I know, what the `inline` keyword does, in a nutshell, is: Instead of creating a function object and generating a call, the compiler copies the block of code and puts it in the place where we want that code to be invoked. The benefit is: better memory allocations.

So its usage is mostly (if not always) related to High-order functions and Lambdas.

This made sense to me until now, when I started looking at how some of the Kotlin extension functions were implemented.

Some examples:

```
/**
 * Returns a random element from this collection.
 * 
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if this collection is empty.
 */
@SinceKotlin("1.3")
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> Collection<T>.random(): T {
    return random(Random)
}
```

```
/**
 * Returns an element at the given [index] or throws an [IndexOutOfBoundsException] if the [index] is out of bounds of this list.
 * 
 * @sample samples.collections.Collections.Elements.elementAt
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> List<T>.elementAt(index: Int): T {
    return get(index)
}
```

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this collection.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> Collection<T>.count(): Int {
    return size
}
```

Can someone explain to me why are these functions marked as `inline`?

If we use `inline` when dealing with High-order functions and Lambdas, and if what I said above is the only benefit of `inline` keyword then these functions should not be `inline`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

There is a microscopic potential runtime overhead for each function call. This is a hyper-optimization, and is only justified here because these functions are (1) in the standard library and therefore are very likely to be used in performance critical code somewhere, and (2) these functions are extremely short so the increased amount of bytecode (if any) from using them is rather trivial.

The downside with using an inline function in most cases is that if you use it in multiple places in your application, your total amount of bytecode in the application is going to be bigger. With the exception of `random()` above, that's not true in your examples, since the content of the inline function is the same amount of code as a single function call anyway.

Comment: Since inline increases the bytecode, then it will also increase the bytecode of the app if we are calling these functions frequently for our code. Also, writing the same function would show a warning "Expected performance impact from inlining is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types".

Comment: Check my last sentence again. It's not going to increase bytecode if the content of the function is the same amount of bytecode as if you wrote it directly in place. The warning is not very sophisticated and won't try to identify cases where it makes sense to use `inline`. It is very rare to need to do this in your own code, so it's just a blanket warning. They do it in the standard library because that code is used by everyone, so it will be used in performance critical sections of code somewhere. Note that they are also working around the warning by using `@InlineOnly` to suppress it.